# what is the difference between string? and string in c#?

Tags: c#, string, null, nullable-reference-types

References types are nullable by default and it is possible to assign a null value to *string*. What is the point of *string?* then? What difference does it make in this case?

Comment: So, you know about "nullable". You know about "reference types". What do you find when you search for those three words together? *Many* articles have been written and *many* questions asked here already.

Comment: [nullable-reference-types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/nullable-reference-types). As of C# 8, these are enabled by default. So declaring a variable as `string?` says that the variable may contain a valid string or `null`, whereas `string` should only contain a valid string value.

Comment: Taken directly from MSDN: "The goal of this feature is to:

Allow developers to express whether a variable, parameter or result of a reference type is intended to be null or not.
Provide warnings when such variables, parameters and results are not used according to that intent."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string?` and `string` are the same type. This is true for all reference types and reference types only.

In a nullable context the `?` is a hint telling that `null` is a valid value for this field, variable, parameter or return value. Omitting `?` on the other hand means that a value of `null` is not expected. It allows the compiler to do a static analysis of your code and to issue a warning when it could result in a null-reference-exception. It also allows you to avoid unnecessary null-checks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **C# 8.0 or later** with nullable reference types enabled, a `string` variable is expected to **never** be `null` and the compiler will issue warnings if it might be set to `null`.

```
string nonNullableString = null; //Compiler warning with nullable reference types enabled
string? nullableString = null; //No compiler warning
```

Answer (score 0):

Functionality is the same but for example when you assign a `null` value to `string` you might get a [CS8600](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings#possible-null-assigned-to-a-nonnullable-reference) warning while with `string?` you won't because you explicitly declared a nullable field.

Answer (score -3):

Many articles have been written about this, but the TLDR is that nullable types was not made until C# 2.0 and therefore it is all a result of history how all is interpreted now. For backward compatibility string without ? has to be nullable.

Comment: Do you mean **nullable reference types**? introduced in **C# 8** / .Net core 3?  AFAIK `null` has existed since C# 1.

Comment: Nullable value types (like int?) was introduced around 2005 (C# 2.0) as far as I recall. String is special, but had the questionmark syntax been introduced along with the language then string and string? would have followed int and int? logic.

Comment: But string is not a value type. Sure, nullable reference types reused the `?` syntax, but `string?` is not valid until c# 8.

Comment: string is special, and one of the two reference types specifically specified in the Ecma spec. (the other being object). When C# 2.0 was released there was a lot of debate about this and it couldn't be done. So what we have today is a combination of history.